# Tukey HSD for mixed continuous and categorical variables, error: "no factors"

Tags: r, anova, categorical-data, continuous

I'm trying to run a Tukey test on mortality data, where I want to test whether mortality is influenced by the amount of copper (in an one-way ANOVA) and the combination of copper and temperature (in a two-way ANOVA). These are my formulas:

```
lm2<-lm(Mortality~Cu) 
anova(lm2) 
TukeyHSD(aov(Mortality~Cu)) 

lm2<-lm(Mortality~Cu+Temp+Cu:Temp) 
anova(lm2) 
TukeyHSD(aov(Mortality~Cu+Temp+Cu:Temp))
```

The ANOVA is no problem, but for both Tukey's, I get the following error message:

```
    Error in TukeyHSD.aov(aov(Mortality ~ Cu + Temp + Cu:Temp)) : 
      no factors in the fitted model 
    In addition: Warning messages: 
    1: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: Cu 
    2: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: Temp 
    3: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : 
      non-factors ignored: Cu, Temp
```

I've read on other posts that there should be a factor somewhere, but all my data are numbers! I'm quite baffled and have no idea what to do next.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Lundill

Comment: `Cu:Temp` expects that `Cu` and/or `Temp` are factors.  So you should convert them.

Answer (score 6):

`TukeyHSD` only works with categorical variables so it's looking for factors in your formula. Are the values of `Cu` discrete bust just coded as numeric values? If so then use

```
fCu<-factor(Cu)
TukeyHSD(aov(Mortality~fCu))
```

Or are the observations continuous? Then you must break it into intervals to turn it into a factor. You could do

```
fCu<-cut(Cu, breaks=4)
TukeyHSD(aov(Mortality~fCu))
```

If only a subset of variables on the right side of the equation are factors, you must specify those explicitly in the `which` parameter of the `TukeyHSD`. So if you use the categorical `fCu` and `Temp` is a continuous numeric variable, you can do

```
TukeyHSD(aov(Mortality~fCu+Temp), which="fCu")
```

though it still issues a warning about the other columns so i'm not sure how to interpret the results

Comment: Thank you so much, MrFlick! That worked perfectly for my data. I'll remember that trick for future analyses. Thanks again!